# pytorch multi-class lstm predicting all one class on testing

Tags: python, deep-learning, classification, pytorch, lstm

I'm working on a project (my first AI project) and I've hit a bit of a wall. When performing testing on my trained classifier, it's predicting that everything is of class 1. Now the data set is heavily biased to class 1; however, I've implemented weights to compensate for this. Just concerned that I've coded this wrong or missed something. Please let me know if you see anything.

This is the setup and training

```
  batchSize = 50

trainingLoad = DataLoader(trainingData, shuffle = True, batch_size = batchSize, drop_last=True)
validationLoad = DataLoader(validationData, shuffle = True, batch_size = batchSize, drop_last=True)
testingLoad = DataLoader(testingData, shuffle = True, batch_size = batchSize, drop_last=True)

vocabularySize = len(wordToNoDict)
output = 3
embedding = 400
hiddenDimension = 524
layers = 4

classifierModel = Classifier.HateSpeechDetector(device, vocabularySize, output, embedding, hiddenDimension, layers)
classifierModel.to(device)

path = 'Program\data\state_dict2.pt'

weights = torch.tensor([1203/1203, 1203/15389, 1203/3407])
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight = weights)

trainClassifier(classifierModel, trainingLoad, validationLoad, device, batchSize, criterion, path)

test(classifierModel, path, testingLoad, batchSize, device, criterion)
def trainClassifier(model, trainingData, validationData, device, batchSize, criterion, path):
epochs = 5
counter = 0
testWithValiEvery = 10
clip = 5
valid_loss_min = np.Inf

lr=0.0001
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)


model.train()

for i in range(epochs):

    h = model.init_hidden(batchSize, device)
    for inputs, labels in trainingData:
        h = tuple([e.data for e in h])
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device) 
        model.zero_grad()
        output, h = model(inputs, h)
        loss = criterion(output.squeeze(), labels.long())
        loss.backward()
        nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), clip)
        optimizer.step()
        counter += 1
        print(counter)

        if counter%testWithValiEvery == 0:
            print("validating")
            val_h = model.init_hidden(batchSize, device)
            val_losses = []
            model.eval()
            for inp, lab in validationData:
                val_h = tuple([each.data for each in val_h])
                inp, lab = inp.to(device), lab.to(device)

                out, val_h = model(inp, val_h)#


                val_loss = criterion(out.squeeze(), lab.long())
                val_losses.append(val_loss.item())

            model.train()
            print("Epoch: {}/{}...".format(i+1, epochs),
                "Step: {}...".format(counter),
                "Loss: {:.6f}...".format(loss.item()),
                "Val Loss: {:.6f}".format(np.mean(val_losses)))
            if np.mean(val_losses) <= valid_loss_min:
                torch.save(model.state_dict(), path)
                print('Validation loss decreased ({:.6f} --> {:.6f}).  Saving model ...'.format(valid_loss_min,np.mean(val_losses)))
                print('model saved')
                valid_loss_min = np.mean(val_losses)
```

This is the classifier - Fair amount of random commenting here where i've meddled with bits

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as op
import torchvision
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms, datasets


class HateSpeechDetector(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, device, vocabularySize, output, embedding, hidden, layers, dropProb=0.5):
        super(HateSpeechDetector, self).__init__()
        #Number of outputs (Classes/Categories)
        self.output = output
        #Number of layers in the LSTM
        self.numLayers = layers
        #Number of hidden neurons in each LSTM layer
        self.hiddenDimensions = hidden
        #Device being used for by model (CPU or GPU)
        self.device = device

        #Embedding layer finds correlations in words by converting word integers into vectors
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocabularySize, embedding)
        #LSTM stores important data in memory, using it to help with future predictions
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embedding,hidden,layers,dropout=dropProb,batch_first=True)
        #Dropout is used to randomly drop nodes. This helps to prevent overfitting of the model during training
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropProb)

        #Establishing 4 simple layers and a sigmoid output
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden, hidden)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden, hidden)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden, hidden)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(hidden, hidden)
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(hidden, hidden)
        self.fc6 = nn.Linear(hidden, output)
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=2)

    def forward(self, x, hidden):
        batchSize = x.size(0)

        x = x.long()

        embeds = self.embedding(x)

        lstm_out, hidden = self.lstm(embeds, hidden)

        #Tensor changes here from 250,33,524 to 8250,524
        # lstm_out = lstm_out.contiguous().view(-1,self.hiddenDimensions)

        out = self.dropout(lstm_out)
        out = self.fc(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        out = self.fc3(out)
        out = self.fc4(out)
        out = self.fc5(out)
        out = self.fc6(out)

        out = self.softmax(out) 

        out = out[:,-1,:]

        # myTensor = torch.Tensor([0,0,0])
        # newOut = torch.zeros(batchSize, self.output)
        # count = 0
        # row = 0

        # for tensor in out:
        #     if(count == 33):
        #         newOut[row] = myTensor/33
        #         myTensor = torch.Tensor([0,0,0])
        #         row += 1
        #         count = 0
        #     myTensor += tensor
        #     count += 1
        return out, hidden

    def init_hidden(self, batchSize, device):
        weight = next(self.parameters()).data

        hidden = (weight.new(self.numLayers, batchSize, self.hiddenDimensions).zero_().to(device), weight.new(self.numLayers, batchSize, self.hiddenDimensions).zero_().to(device))

        return hidden
```

Comment: In your classifier, you haven't used activation functions between Linear layers. So, all your Linear layers become just a single Linear layer (as far as learning capacity is concerned). So, add the activation functions (like ReLU) and retrain.

Answer (score 0):

You've added weights to the cross-entropy loss, and the weights bias towards the first class already (`[1.0, 0.08, 0.35]`).

Having a higher weight for a certain class means that the model will be more heavily penalized for getting that class wrong, and it's possible for the model to learn to just predict everything as the class with highest weight. Usually you don't need to manually assign weights.

Also, check your data to see if there's label imbalance, i.e., whether you have more training examples that are of the first class. An imbalanced training set has similar effects as setting different weights on the loss.

Comment: Hi, the reason for the weighting is that the data is heavily biased with 1203 of one class, 3407 of another and 15389 of the final one.

Comment: @ashleyanniss I see, I guess that makes sense. Have you tried evaluating on the training set? Do you observe the loss decreasing when training?